# Batch To get Count Of 0 Byte Files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to run a batch to get the number of 0 byte files in a directory. If the count is one or more then I want to delete the files otherwise quit. Here is what I have so far.

```
@echo off
if "%~z1" == "" (
   echo File does not exist.
) else if "%~z1" == "0" (
   echo File is empty.
) else (
   echo File is non-empty.
)
```

Answer (score 4):

*(Edited, see comments. Original answer below.)*

The following script counts empty files in a directory, then, if the count turns out greater than `0`, deletes the empty files. The directory is specified as a parameter to the batch script. For example, if you need to process the directory of `C:\Users\DS\Downloads`, call the script like this (assuming `script.bat` is the script file's name):

```
script.bat C:\Users\DS\Downloads
```

This is the script:

```
@ECHO OFF

IF "%~1" == "" (ECHO Usage: %~nx0 path\to\files& GOTO :EOF)

SET "workdir=%~1"

SET count=0
SET "command=SET /A count+=1"
CALL :processempty
ECHO Number of empty files: %count%

IF %count% GTR 0 (
  ECHO Deleting files...
  SET "command=DEL ^"%%~F^""
  CALL :processempty
)
GOTO :EOF

:processempty
FOR %%F IN ("%workdir%\*") DO (
  IF "%%~zF" == "0" %command%
)
```

---

*Original answer follows:*

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET firstfile=
SET delfirstfile=
FOR %%F IN (*) DO (
  IF "%%~zF" == "0" (
    IF DEFINED firstfile (
      ECHO DEL "%%F"
      SET delfirstfile=1
    ) ELSE (
      SET "firstfile=%%F"
    )
  )
)
IF DEFINED delfirstfile ECHO DEL "%firstfile%"
ENDLOCAL
```

The above script works like this:

1. It iterates through all the files in the current directory and checks their sizes.
2. When the first empty file is found, its name is stored into a variable.
3. Every subsequent empty file is deleted and another variable is set to indicate that the first empty file should be deleted too.
4. After the loop the indicator variable is checked. If it is set, the first empty file is deleted.

PS. I would suggest you first to run this script as is to make sure it works correctly. Afterwards you'll need to remove `ECHO` in front of each of the two `DEL` commands to let the script actually remove files.

Comment: Thank you.  I need it to work in this framework.  The directory needs to be c:\Users\DS\Downloads Then I need an if statement like this.....If count >= 1  then "delete" elseif count = 0 then do nothing.

Comment: @ME-dia: You mean you first want only to count empty files, *then* take decision whether to delete them? That would probably require iterating over the directory twice. Are you sure? Also, in what way do you want the working directory to be set? For example, could you just `CD` to it just before calling the script?

Comment: Yes! Thats it. Only empty files.  CD would be fine.  But I need the count thing because if the count is 1 or greater I call a small C++ applet otherwise if its 0 then I do nothing. Thank you.

Comment: @ME-dia: It may be hard to believe and I myself have no idea how that happened but somehow I managed to misread your question. Instead of *'If the count is one or more…'* I read *'If the count is **more than one**…'*! That was so silly of me, sorry. Now I've tried to amend my mistake by posting a different solution. Your comments have been taken into account too. Please have a look.

Comment: This script errors for me on files it cannot find if there are spaces in the filename.

Comment: @Sawtaytoes: Corrected the code, please try the updated script. Thanks for catching the error.